# Flutter - How to pass search text from one widget to its another class widget while searching?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have one search view in main statefull widget class and one listview in another widget class.
Now when user search something I wanna pass search text to listview widget to call api.

so how can I do this?

When first time open list then is will work but when I search something then how can I call it again?

My code snippet is below.

[image]

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Flex(
          direction: Axis.vertical,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Divider(
              color: ColorsApp.gray,
              height: 1,
            ),
            searchView(),
            Expanded(
              child: OrderList(
                isSearch: isSearch,
                textSearch: textSearch,
                onCallBack: widget.onCalBack,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
```

now on search text change

```
 void _onTextChange(String value) {
    print(tag + "....value........" + value);

    if (value == "") {
      _writtingStatusController.add(true);
      _customSearchViewController.add(false);
      setState(() {
        textSearch = "";
        isSearch = true;
      });
    } else {
      _writtingStatusController.add(false);
      _customSearchViewController.add(true);
      setState(() {
        textSearch = value;
        isSearch = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Order List class

```
class OrderList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String textSearch;
  final bool isSearch;
  final Function onCallBack;

  const OrderList({
    Key key,
    this.textSearch,
    this.onCallBack,
    this.isSearch,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderListState createState() => _OrderListState();
}
```

Comment: Add your `searchView()` method also. Your `search` and `list` are in one widget (file/route).

Comment: I wanna pass search text to ORDER LIST class when I search something. So how can I pass SEARCH TEXT every time to ORDER LIST class and how can I get it to ORDER LIST Class because when it passes init method is not call every time.

Comment: no I did not use stream builder 

Can you give me one example how to use it in this scenario?

Comment: My text search class is different and order list class is different but both are in one page in design. I make two class widgets so my concern is only that how can I pass search text to another class widget when I search something.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the `onChanged` method from the parent.

```
class SearchView extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(String) onChanged;

  const SearchView({Key key, this.onChanged}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
        ...
        TextField(
          ...
          onChanged: this.onChanged,
          ...
        ),
        ...
  }
}
```

And then in the parent:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Flex(
      direction: Axis.vertical,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Divider(
          color: ColorsApp.gray,
          height: 1,
        ),
        SearchView(
            onChanged: _onChanged,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: OrderList(
            isSearch: isSearch,
            textSearch: textSearch,
            onCallBack: widget.onCalBack,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my question is bit different

I asked for how to pass textsearch to ORDER LIST class and get text search there

because I want textsearch every time to that widget class when I type something.